# How do I get the current URL via an initializer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to implement Rackismet on a system which uses multiple domain names. Rakismet suggests doing the following using a Proc in the initializer or in the application.rb. (https://github.com/joshfrench/rakismet/blob/master/README.md#getting-started)

```
config.rakismet.url = Proc.new { ApplicationController.current_tenant.url }
```

I tried this but it doesn't work. I get...

```
ApplicationController.current_tenant
!! #<NoMethodError: undefined method `current_tenant' for ApplicationController:Class>
```

Does anyone know the correct way of achieving this?

Comment: do you have a `current_tenant` method defined on your app or you're expecting that the method is added after you install the gem?

Comment: I don't have that method defined. I'd assumed it was part of the gem or built into Rails.